# U-Boot Application that can access all files on USB Flash Drive

Tags: u-boot

I just started learning about U-Boot and being able to write applications that can be run with U-Boot, so please be patient and if possible add more details to help me learn.

I wanted to ask for help, as I am trying to connect USB flash drive to my Arm Cortex A9 device. I want to be able to have access to all files on that drive through my U-Boot script. For example what I write will just run after U-Boot loads, and will be as simple as reading all files.

I plan to use U-Boot, so that I have access to all U-Boot drivers. U-boot supports USB, and I am able to see my USB Flash Drive on the U-boot command line. How can this be done, any help is HIGHLY appreciated please.

Comment: Your title makes no sense, since USB is a bus, rather than a device.  Data on a storage device (e.g. flash drive) can be accessed from the raw device or can be organized as a file in some type of filesystem (e.g. VFAT, ext2/3/4).  These capabilities are options for U-Boot, so if they are not configured and built into your copy of U-Boot, then they are not available at runtime.  BTW you mention *"applications"* and *"scripts"* almost interchangeably; those are two completely different capabilities in U-Boot.

Comment: Sorry about the wrong word usage, tried to fix it above. I'm still trying to understand all of this, so I may not have the right picture yet, thus the wrong words. Once again, I apologize.